# How to fix 'tensorflow:Saver not created because there are no variables in the graph to restore' in Python (Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, object-detection

In the object_detection_tutorial for tensorflow, I keep getting a 'tensorflow:Saver not created...' error when loading the model.

I'm still beginning to learn about tensorflow so I'm unsure about how to go about it.

```py
model_name = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17'
detection_model = load_model(model_name)
```

INFO:tensorflow:Saver not created because there are no variables in the graph to restore

The expected result are the detected objects in the images later on but it wont output anything due to the error above.